# Loop through elements in map function in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, amazon-web-services, aws-amplify

I'm trying to loop though an element inside a map function.

```
const set = new Set(["I", "deck"," Yes."]);
const arr =  value.sort((a, b) => a.id - b.id)

return <RightWrapper>
   { arr.map(transcript => (<p key={transcript.id}style= 
   {{color:set.has(transcript.Transcription) ? 'red' : 'black'
   }} >{transcript.createdAt + "  " + transcript.Transcription + " "} </p> )) }
    </RightWrapper>;
```

In the code above I want to iterate over transcribe.Transcription (inside map function ) and check if any word is in the set. If yes then apply the style otherwise don't.

Comment: what is your issue? please state the issue

Comment: @Minsaf I have reframed the question. Please have a look

Comment: You need to describe the problem. What worked, what didn't. To get good responses see [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you are stuck at logic inside your map function or you not able to map HTML elements. If you are not able to map HTML elements, then here is a codeSandbox.
https://codesandbox.io/s/map-over-elements-vjo0r1